# Drupal 7 embeded comment form in node

Tags: forms, drupal-7, comments

so at the bottom of my node I have

This provides a link to add comments but I would like the form to appear without having to click the link is this possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this hook in your template.php file for your theme:
    function THEMENAME_form_comment_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
    }

Then use
$form['#collapsible'] = FALSE;

You can see more details for forms here:
http://www.digett.com/blog/05/26/2011/how-theme-comment-form-drupal-7